# How to pass fetched data as props to a component with react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a component with data from a API, but i don't find a way to pass the data as props to my 'Episode' component.

Here is the code:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const url = 'https://swapi.co/api/films/'


function Episode(props){
  return (
    <div>
      {props.title}
      {props.release_date}
    </div>
  )
}


function App() {

  const [content, setContent] = useState(null)

  useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const data = await response.json()
    const [...movies] = data.results
    setContent(movies)
  }, [])


  return (
    <div>
      {content && <Episode movie={content[0]}/>}
    </div>
  )

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your data is in a `movie` prop:

```
<Episode movie={content[0]}/>
```

So in your component you need to access `props.movie`:

```
function Episode(props){
  return (
    <div>
      {props.movie.title}
      {props.movie.release_date}
    </div>
  )
}
```