# Pass asynchronous data as props using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid

I am trying to create an Ag-grid table as a common component such that any new component can use Grid component by just calling Grid component and passing the data. I need to pass data to the grid component. I fetch data from a chain of apis using async and await and then I would like to send the fetched data as a prop to the Grid Component. This is how I am doing currently:

Grid Component:

```
const Grid = ({props}) => {
    
    const [gridrowData, setGridRowData] = useState([]);
    const [gridcolumns, setGridColumns] = useState([]);
    const gridRef = useRef(null);
    let columnDefinitions = [];
    
  
    useEffect((props) => {
        const sampleTableData = props.tableData;
        sampleTableData.map(object => {
            Object
                .keys(object)
                .map(key => {
                    let mappedColumn = {
                        headerName: key.toUpperCase(),
                        field: key
                    }

                    columnDefinitions.push(mappedColumn);
                });
        })
        setGridColumns(columnDefinitions);

        setGridRowData(moddedRowData);

    },[]);
```

Child component:

```
const ListPage = ({...props}) => {
    const testData = [];
    const [gridData, setGridData] = useState([]);
    const gridRef = useRef(null);
    let columnDefinitions = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        const getResources = async() => {
            try {
                
                const personalGroup = await getPersonalGroup(resourceId).then((responseData) => responseData.result);
                const resources = await getPersonalResourceId(personalGroup, 24)
                    .then((resourceData) => resourceData);
                const testData = await Promise.all(
                    resources.map(async (resourceId) => {
                        const resources = await getIndividualResourceId(resourceId)
                            .then((resources) => resources);
                        return resources;
                    }))
                
                const [...apiData] = testData;
                setGridData(apiData);
 catch(err) {
                console.error(err);
            }

getResources();
    }, []);


    return (
        <Box align='center' fill='vertical' justify='center'>
            <div className="ag-theme-alpine-dark" style={{ height: "100%", width: 
             "100%"}}>
                {gridData && <Grid tableData={gridData} {...props}/>}
</div>
        </Box>
    );
```

[image]

testData and apiData does retrieve the data.
But I get props.tableData to be undefined. Its still trying to create grid before the data fetching is done. How can I fix this ? Am I passing the props correctly ?
I did follow this stackoverflow link :
[How to pass fetched data as props to a component with react hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58468769/how-to-pass-fetched-data-as-props-to-a-component-with-react-hooks)
but I still get undefined when I try to access that prop data.

Comment: Where are you using `props.GridData`? Your `Grid` components uses `props.tableData` not `props.gridData`

Comment: Yes, props.tableData is undefined. Eventually I will be using the tableData to set rows and columns of the grid.

Comment: Hm, either I misread or you edited it haha. Have you tried using `console.log` in `getResources` function to see if the data is actually retrieved?

Comment: Yes I did edit it! Data is being retrieved in child component. Its only the passing of data to Grid Component that is not working :( Do you think the way I am passing is correct ?

Comment: I get that the data is retrieved in the child component, my question was more if you're sure the data is actually fetched. In other words, what does your `testData` look like inside the `getResources` function.

Comment: testData is an array of objects. I added screenshot of it to the question if that helps.